# How to show gmail calendar on ios application?

Tags: ios, gmail

I have a `Gmail calendar` with a lot of events.

Now I'm developing an `iOS` app and want to show this calendar in a view, but I don't know how to do it because of `iOS` haven't any controllers for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was looking for a way to do that i need. I found this tutorial but i have not tested it yet because i cant use the calendar on iOS Simulator.

You can launch an iPhone/iPad application like calendar (my case), telephone etc with this tutorial:

[Launching iPhone Apps With Custom URL Scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html)

For the calendar, i think that u have to use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
```

Anyway i cant test this code cause calendar is just enable on a iPad/iPhone and not in the Simulator.

**Yet not as I could do to gmail calendar.**